# Formula to conditionally format a cell if the cell value (text) is not in row above

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need a formula to format a cell if the value of the cell is not in the row above.

I have to compare 100 rows of 10 columns sorted by date with the column above it.

Column A has the date and columns B-J the text that need to be compared to the previous row:

```
Columns...    A       B    C    D    E    F    G  ... J
              Date1   A    B    C    D    E    F
              Date2   C    E    A    J    D    K
              Date3   C    E    A    J    D    K
```

Comment: Could you give more information? are you using excel??

Comment: Sorry, Yes using excel 2010

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear, try rephrasing it in a way that's easier to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: sample data  item names shorted to a letter for this example

DATE1    A      B      C     D     E     F
DATE2    C      E      A     ***J***   D     ***K***
DATE3    C      E      A     J     D     K

Bold letters need to be highlighted and conditional formatting applied on all rows.

hope this clears things up.  
Doug

Comment: +1 there we go, see, you got some good answers too

Answer (score 0):

Click Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format. The formula I think you want is:

```
=E2<>B3
```

Which means E2 is not equal to B3.

I think in your case, you might do something like:

```
=C3<>B3
```

You could change the `B3` to a range of cells if you want. If you added a screenshot, it would help.

This is what I got while testing:

[image]

In this, I put the conditional formatting on B3 and E3. B3's formula was `=E2<>B3` and E3's formula was `=E2<>E3`

If the text is not in the cell (or row if you do something like `B3:F3`), then it highlights it with whatever you chose when setting the formatting up.

Comment: I think this might work I would attach an image but can't figure out how.  I set CF for cell that contains to not = to and put the range for the row above.  I did this for all the columns but not sure how to "drag" the CF down the sheet like I would a formula.

Comment: disregard above comment.    I set CF for cell that contains to not = to and put the range for the row above and to fill the cell but it fills the cell even if it is in the above row

Comment: @doug just to make sure it is working, please try doing this with no cell range (ie. only one cell after the `<>` and tell me if this works. Thanks. You could temporarily attach an image to your question

Comment: I figured it out.  In CF I put =countif(range of row-1,columnrow)=0 and picked fill color

Comment: Great! Happy to know that you got it working finally.

Comment: @doug I recommend you make your own answer for this as nobody else answered it the way you preferred. It may help future users

Answer (score 0):

Switch to R1C1 editing mode.

Select the whole table then add a new conditional rule.

Enter the formula:

```
=or(RC2<>R[-1]C2, RC3<>R[-1]C3, RC4<>R[-1]C4, RC5<>R[-1]C5, RC6<>R[-1]C6, RC7<>R[-1]C7, RC8<>R[-1]C8, RC9<>R[-1]C9)
```

And add suitable formatting.

What will now happen is that if any of the 9 tested columns in the current row are different to the matching columns in the row above (-1), the format will be applied. Note that you apply this to the whole table which means that the whole row will be highlighted if any of the columns don't match their previous values, this stands out much better than individually highlighting single columns that don't match their previous values.

You can do that without R1C1 of course but I find it much easier to work in that mode when doing calculations like this.

The only problem with this is that the first data row is going to be different to the titles and so will always be highlighted. Either exclude the first 2 rows (title and first data row) from the formatting or make the formula more complex so that it returns FALSE for all columns in the first two rows.

This also is only really feasible when you don't have too many columns. If you do, you could create a catenated column that you hide as the last column and just test that (as long as the catenation doesn't make the text too long to fit in a cell). If neither of those work, you might consider using VBA to detect changes and reformat.

Comment: this is part of a large active worksheet if I switched to r1c1 for editing will that be for whole workbook or just a section?  also wasn't sure how to pasted into formula to determine which cells to format for all rows.

Comment: It is for everything, the setting is in options. However, it is reversible and won't harm any formulae. The formula I gave should be the single one you put in having selected all the cells and then insert the condition. It applies to all cells the same.

Comment: Just make a copy and have a play so you can see what happens.

Comment: I perhaps should have made clear that you can switch to R1C1 temporarily, I recommend it because it seems much clearer to me when doing row comparisons like this. Just switch it back after you have entered the conditional formula & you will be able to see the formula in the traditional way.